# Why can you create an object from an array literal when a struct doesn't conform to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, protocols

I'm looking through a book and they've implemented a stack using a `struct` with a generic type. The generic type is then used in an array that serves as the stack. Later, they are able to create an instance of the `struct` using an array literal. I know that they extended the `struct` to conform to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` somehow, but the Apple documentation shows a different `init` method format from the book's `init` method. How is this possible?

Here is the `struct`:

```
public struct Stack<Element> { 
    private var storage: [Element] = []
    public init(_ elements: [Element]) {
    storage = elements
}
```

Here is the `extension`:

```
extension Stack: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...) {
        storage = elements
  }
}
```

The `init` method above is different from the Apple example of conformance shown here (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral):

```
extension OrderedSet: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral: Element...) {
        self.init()
        for element in arrayLiteral {
            self.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the closure in the book that is used to instantiate a `Stack`:

```
example(of: "initializing a stack from an array literal") {
    var stack: Stack = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    print(stack)
    stack.pop()
}
```

Comment: Read about [function argument labels](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166). The method signature has the same arguments, but the parameter name in non-Apple example is different.

Comment: Thank you so much. This definitely answers my question, I will write up an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to New Dev for the help on this question.

It turns out that the method signature both `init` methods have the same argument labels. The fact that both of them have the same argument labels means that the book's example does in fact conform to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.

In the book's example, they are specifying a parameter name explicitly in addition to the argument label that is required.